# Вернуть значение из метода

Tags: c#, .net, aop, postsharp

Используя библиотеки PostSharp, можно ли сделать так, что бы при условии вернулось определенное значение из метода? Например ставим атрибут на аргументе (которое число) в методе (где возвращаем тоже число): если число меньше нуля, то вернем просто ноль. Или если аргумент - ссылочный тип и равен null.

p.s. понятно, что задача решается строкой кода в теле метода, это всего-лишь псевдо-задание на котором удобно показать.

**UPD**
Что-то вроде этого:

```
public class FooClass
{
    public FooClass( [NotEmpty] string field )
    {
        FieldStr = field;
    }

    public string FooValue( [IfNull("Empty")] string source )
    {
        return source;
    }

    public readonly string FieldStr;
}

internal class IfNullAttribute : Attribute
{
    private string v;

    public IfNullAttribute(string v)
    {
        this.v = v;
    }

    public string ReturnValue() => v;
}
```

Comment: можете пример кода добавить как бы вы хотели использовать?

Comment: @Grundy, добавил псевдокод в шапку.

Comment: что-то вроде параметров по умолчанию?

Comment: @Grundy, да, именно оно

Comment: эм, а стандартное не подойдет? `public string FooValue( string source = "Empty")`?

Comment: @Grundy "Empty" надо вернуть в случае если `source == null`.

Comment: @andreycha, ага, это уже интереснее :-) так можно? :)

Comment: @Grundy с помощью AOP можно все! Главное знать, как :).

Comment: @andreycha, логично :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Более гибкий вариант, с установкой атрибутов на параметрах и с возможностью определения дополнительных условий. Однако без атрибута уровня метода не обойтись, поскольку вернуть управление из метода возможно только в аспекте метода.

Определяем атрибут для метода, который поддерживает ранний выход:

```
[Serializable]
public class EarlyReturnAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        ParameterInfo[] parameters = args.Method.GetParameters();

        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
        {
            foreach (var attribute in parameters[i].GetCustomAttributes<EarlyReturnConditionAttribute>())
            {
                if (attribute.MeetsCondition(args.Arguments[i]))
                {
                    args.ReturnValue = attribute.ReturnValue;
                    args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        base.OnEntry(args);
    }
}
```

Определяем атрибуты для параметров. Для задания конкретных условий раннего выхода наследуемся от `EarlyReturnConditionAttribute`:

```
public abstract class EarlyReturnConditionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public EarlyReturnConditionAttribute(object returnValue)
    {
        ReturnValue = returnValue;
    }

    public object ReturnValue { get; }

    public abstract bool MeetsCondition(object value);
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class IfNullAttribute: EarlyReturnConditionAttribute
{
    public IfNullAttribute(object returnValue) : base(returnValue)
    {
    }

    public override bool MeetsCondition(object value)
    {
        return value == null;
    }
}
```

Используем:

```
public class FooClass
{
    [EarlyReturn]
    public string FooValue([IfNull("Empty")]string source)
    {
        return source;
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем необходимость вызова базового метода перед выходом из переопределенного?

Comment: @anweledig базовый метод вызовется только если не сработает ранний выход. Поскольку я реализации базового метода не видел (возможно он не пустой), то лучше его вызывать в "нормальном сценарии".

Answer (score 3):

С помощью PostSharp это можно сделать следующим образом:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new FooClass();
        Console.WriteLine(foo.FooValue("foo")); // foo
        Console.WriteLine(foo.FooValue(null)); // bar
    }
}

public class FooClass
{
    [ResultAspect]
    public string FooValue(string source)
    {
        return source;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class ResultAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Arguments[0] == null)
            args.ReturnValue = "bar";

        base.OnExit(args);
    }
}
```

Создаём аспект, унаследованный от `OnMethodBoundaryAspect`. Помечаем им нужный метод. Через параметр `args` можно получить значения аргументов, с которым метод был вызван. Через него же можно установить выходное значение.

---

> A можно это сделать из OnEntry? Чтобы моментально вернуть значение, чтобы null не попал в тело метода, где нет проверки.

Можно:

```
public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
{
    if (args.Arguments[0] != null)
        base.OnEntry(args);
}
```

Или, как предложил **andreycha**, наследоваться от `MethodInterceptionAspect`:

```
[Serializable]
public class ResultAspect2 : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Arguments[0] != null)
            base.OnInvoke(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: а чтобы атрибут был у параметра, а не на самом методе?

Comment: Метод-интерсептор -- самое легкое решение, но не самое удобное в использовании. Что, если параметров несколько? Что, если на каждый из них хочется свое условие? Помечать метод атрибутом типа `[Result("paramName", "value")]` или `[Result(%paramIndex%, "value")]` не самое статически типизированное решение.

Comment: классный вариант, а можно это сделать из OnEtry? Что бы моментально вернуть значение, что бы null не попал в тело метода где нет проверки.

Comment: @anweledig можно. Как вариант еще можно наследоваться от `MethodInterceptionAspect` и переопределять `OnInvoke`.